# How to apply alternate background color for each column in CSS columns

Tags: css

How to apply alternate background color to multi column layout based on column count.

[image]

In the above link, if u see all the column background is blue, i want to give alternate background color of white & blue

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus aliquam commodo vestibulum. Duis in risus auctor, posuere elit a, interdum nunc. Vivamus nisl velit, vehicula ut ornare ac, mollis sit amet lectus. Praesent volutpat erat sem, id accumsan arcu tempor et. Quisque elementum leo sed elit volutpat, cursus dapibus lorem bibendum. Vivamus porta, elit sed facilisis tincidunt, enim diam suscipit metus, sit amet tincidunt ipsum augue id erat. Duis eget mi enim. Donec volutpat metus ut lacus iaculis cursus et eleifend orci. Vestibulum sollicitudin nibh sit amet laoreet dignissim. Pellentesque vulputate, leo eu commodo imperdiet, felis ante faucibus mi, vitae bibendum velit ipsum id arcu. Praesent a rhoncus quam, vel viverra elit. Nullam tellus velit, porta eu interdum quis, porttitor sed elit. Pellentesque egestas nisi odio, eget placerat nibh rhoncus id.</p>  
    <p>Vestibulum ante risus, placerat at egestas sit amet, interdum rhoncus leo. Donec libero nunc, aliquam aliquet massa non, fringilla consectetur est. Proin sodales vehicula ante pretium mollis. Proin laoreet vel dui a elementum. Pellentesque et ante odio. Cras commodo nisi sit amet mi pharetra, quis rhoncus tortor sodales. Etiam rhoncus orci nibh, id tincidunt nisi semper non. Quisque a imperdiet purus. Maecenas malesuada quis libero eu viverra. Proin eu diam accumsan, rutrum turpis eget, fermentum diam. Integer sem enim, hendrerit rhoncus suscipit sit amet, rutrum id lectus.</p>
    <p>Suspendisse potenti. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus leo tortor, vestibulum vel odio sed, tincidunt dictum urna. Ut ullamcorper lobortis lacus, at tristique massa posuere vel. Proin aliquam quam tellus, elementum suscipit mauris elementum nec. Proin aliquet quam ligula, sed vulputate nisl sodales sed. Sed erat turpis, iaculis ac nulla eu, dapibus adipiscing elit. Fusce adipiscing nunc mi, ac tempus nunc interdum gravida.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container {
    background-color: blue

    color:#000;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #111111;

    /* column specific styling */
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3em;
    column-rule: 1px dashed black;
}
```

Comment: Can you reword that to explain what you're trying to achieve please?

Comment: I've edited your question as an example of how to properly ask a question on Stack Overflow. It shows example code as well as the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SERIOUS HACK, but as long as you have a fixed width container, it should do what you need.

[image]

I don't have time to fiddle with the widths, but if you spend the time, you "could" theoretically use a `gradient` with hard edges to achieve the desired result. It will also help if you use the dashed `column-rule` to hide/obfuscate the blurred line between containers.

http://jsfiddle.net/r8G2X/2/

```
.container {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        right top,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.67, #324FA2),
        color-stop(0.66, #51C26F),
        color-stop(0.33, #7091EA),
        color-stop(0.34, #51C26F)
    );

    color:#000;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #111111;

            border-radius:5px;
       -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;

            column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;

            column-gap: 3em;
       -moz-column-gap: 3em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3em;

            column-rule: 1px dashed black;
       -moz-column-rule: 1px dashed black;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px dashed black;
}
```

Comment: GREAT!! This is what i want. I have so many ul li (4 levels of nested ul li) within a div. So working on odd or even of li wont help. My width & number of column is fixed. SO your answer works. GREAT.... Thank You

Comment: please be sure to accept/upvote the answer if it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  So, you have many divs / columns and you want every other one to be a different colour?

Assign the element a class and use similar to what I put below.  You then just give every other element the class that dictates the colour

```
 <div id="white">some stuff</div>
    <div id="black">some other stuff</div>

CSS:

#white{
background:white;
}
#black{
background:black;
}
```

Is that what you mean?  ONe div is one colour and another is something different or sis you mean something else?

Comment: can you please check the above link, there is only one div class="container" ---- splitted into three columns using column-count:3. Want to apply alternate background color

Comment: I don't think or know of a way that you can.  If there is only one element being targeted by the css I don't see how it can alternate.  If I were trying to accomplish that I'd probably set up the age as 3 divs with borders to imitate the columns

Comment: Any suggestion? - Yes i am targeting only one element based on column-count. If its able to split into 3/5 columns based on column-count. I need a way to apply different background color to the same element based on the column. First column one background color, next column different background color

Comment: No big shot guy to tackle this issue!!

Comment: The answer is that  you can't. If you split the information into physical `<div>` containers, you can use the `nth-child(odd|even);` properties.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work in your particular case but would you consider applying a background image behind the container? For a three column layout, the background image would consist of three bands of colour (primary colour, alternate colour, primary colour), etc. For a different number of columns, you would use a different background image. Then just use a class on the containing  to specify which should be loaded. To keep the image size down and accommodate any height of column, use a vertically repeating background image.

This assumes that you know the width of each column of course, so for a responsive website might not work. But, on paper at least, I think that would work…